# TimeStamp in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, timestamp

I have a table named `Table1` which contains an `ID` and `TimeStamp`.

Table structure

```
ID  TimeStamp
1   0x0000000000047509
```

But when I compare the combination of these fields, it always shows false. What is the reason for this?

My Query is :

```
 DECLARE @ID int
 DECLARE  @TimeStamp  timestamp

 SET @ID = 1
 SET @TimeStamp = 0x0000000000047509

 If EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @ID AND TimeStamP = @TimeStamp)
 BEGIN
       SELECT 1 AS RetVal
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
       SELECT -1 AS RetVal
 END
```

**My stored procedure is as follows**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Check] (
@XMLDoc  ntext
)AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 SET XACT_ABORT ON 

 DECLARE @ID  bigint
 DECLARE @TimeStamp  timestamp
 DECLARE @hDoc   int

 EXEC sp_xml_PrepareDocument @hDoc OUT, @XMLDoc

 SELECT   @ID  = ID
  ,@TimeStamp = [TimeStamp]
 FROM OPENXML (@hdoc,'/XML')
 WITH (   ID  bigint  'ID'
  ,[TimeStamp] timestamp 'TStamp')

 IF @@ERROR<>0 
 BEGIN
   EXEC sp_xml_RemoveDocument @hDoc 
   SELECT -620 AS RetVal
   RETURN   
 END

 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID=  @ID AND Timestamp = @TimeStamp   )
 BEGIN
       SELECT -1 AS RetVal 
 END
         ELSE
         BEGIN
                SELECT 1 AS RetVal 
         END


END
```

Answer (score 1):

That's odd, the query works fine for me in SQL Server 2005, compatibility mode 80.

The only thing that jumps out to me is that `Timestamp` is a reserved word, so to be on the safe side you might want to add brackets around `Timestamp` to escape it as follows:

```
If EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE [ID] = @ID AND [TimeStamP] = @TimeStamp) ...
```

Comment: it is not working for me in Sql 2000.Have u checked this in 2000?

Comment: @Adu - yes, this worked for me in SQL 2000 as well.  Are the datatypes for ID and Timestamp `int` and `timestamp` respectively?

Comment: the datatype for ID is bigint

Comment: Is this a query done through Query Analyzer or through a stored procedure?

Comment: i have used it in a storedProcedure

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you are calling the procedure?  Are you passing the timestamp in as a varchar by chance?

Comment: Yeah, that would have been helpful to have up front... I'll take a look at this and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

@TimeStamp is not being resolved correctly from the XML. Try CASTing it to binary(8).

The stored proc does not match the query you posted earlier